# Cygwin - Email - New Line (Carriage Return) (How to)

Tags: bash, email, cygwin

using Cygwin on Windows 8, Quick Bash script to search server for files modified in the past 120 days: 
Run once a week as a Cron job, But i cannot format the email.

All i want is a simple New Line:

```
data=$(find /cygdrive/g/SERVERPATH -mtime -120 -name "*.exe"  -exec stat -c "%n : %y" {} \;) ; [[ -n "$data" ]] && email -s 'Servers Latest Files' EMAIL@DOMAINNAME.COM <<< "The following files have been detected as updated in the last 120 days <br> $data"
```

$Data Search from Grep. 
All i want  is to new Line between text and $Data

I tried using Echo -e or printf with no luck. 
using simple /r does not work.

is it a matter of defining the email as HTML format and passing through 
 as i am currently doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. 
Simply writing down, normally dummys it enough for my brain to click in.

Pass HTML option and just use HTML formatting:

```
email -html -s
```

So for a working example:

```
data=$(find /cygdrive/g/SERVERPATH -mtime -120 -name "*.exe"  -exec stat -c "%n : %y" {} \;) ; [[ -n "$data" ]] && email -html -s 'Servers Latest Files' EMAIL@DOMAINNAME.COM <<< "The following files have been detected as updated in the last 120 days <br> $data"
```

Sorry for posting this and wasting ones times